Difference between reverse proxy and inbound rule in IIS
I have two servers as below.

DMZ
Web Server

This DMZ (or we can call it reverse proxy?) will receive all requests from internet and pass it on the web server where actual website is hosted.
So, for e.g. request stackoverflow.com?param1=val1&param2=val2 will be sent to Web Server from DMZ.
Both are Windows based IIS. My question is, which rule shall I define in IIS of DMZ? Shall I define a reverse proxy rule or an inbound rule in URL rewriting? What is the difference between two?

Reverse proxy rules require ARR to be installed, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59
